# shader=interp pdf cannot be included in Lua

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, luatex, shading

I think the problem is exactly the same as reported one year ago [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233278/importing-pdf-image-with-filled-surfaces-using-graphicx), but I hope this time it is reproducible by someone. To verify it is still present in the lastest `LuaLaTeX`, I've just done an update and now run Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6200 64-bit).

I generate a plot (`content.tex`) which uses `shader=interp` by

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
         \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, samples=10, domain=0:1] {x^2*y};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is an example code taken from the `pgfplots` manual and compiles nicely. If I now include this image into another document,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
   \includegraphics{content.pdf}
\end{document}
```

the plot itself does not appear, only the coordinate system. However, if I compile with `pdfLaTeX`, everything works fine (and I have just checked `XeLaTeX`, which also does the job).

Comment: It works as expected for me (using a luatex1.01 build over a texlive 2016 installation)

Comment: Perhaps it is MikTeX related - someone with MikTeX out there for testing?

Comment: I see the issue on Windows with LuaTeX in TeX Live and MiKTeX, but not on the Mac. Presumably it's something to do with the library support.